# Entity Framework LInq Query Lambda Syntax Where Clause

Tags: sql-server, lambda, linq-to-entities, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am trying to use the Include, ThenInclude and Where clause to produce the proper data from the database. This will work fine when When check the equality of the Id property in the where clause. But if i check for the equlity of a string it doesnt work.

Database:

Linq Query 1:

```
public List<Company> GetGateways()
{
    return DbSet
        .Include(c => c.Elements).ThenInclude(e => e.Attributes)
        .Include(c => c.Elements).ThenInclude(e => e.ElementType).Where(o => o.Id == 1)
        .Include(o => o.Users)
        .ToList();
}
```

SQL output:

```
   SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[Active], [a].[Created], [a].[ElementId], [a].

    [Key], [a].[Updated], [a].[Value]
    FROM [Attributes] AS [a]
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT [c].[Id], [e].[Id] AS [Id0]
        FROM [Elements] AS [e]
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT [c].[Id]
            FROM [Companies] AS [c]
            WHERE [c].[Id] = 1
        ) AS [c] ON [e].[CompanyId] = [c].[Id]
    ) AS [e] ON [a].[ElementId] = [e].[Id0]
    ORDER BY [e].[Id], [e].[Id0]
```

Linq Query 2: (Does not Work)

```
public List<Company> GetGateways()
{
    return DbSet
        .Include(c => c.Elements).ThenInclude(e => e.Attributes)
        .Include(c => c.Elements).ThenInclude(e => e.ElementType).Where(o => o.Name == "Gateway")
        .Include(o => o.Users)
        .ToList();
}
```

SQL Output 2:

```
SELECT [c].[Id], [c].[Active], [c].[Created], [c].[Name], [c].[Updated]
FROM [Companies] AS [c]
WHERE [c].[Name] = 'Gateway'
ORDER BY [c].[Id]
```

Any ideas where i am going wrong with my linq query?

Comment: EF will not let you choose what is loaded when using an Include. You can use projection instead to achieve what you want:

Comment: Why does it work when i use the Id and it doesn't work when i use Name?

Comment: Which version on EF7 are you using? As I tried replicating this last night and nothing was being included in the SQL when using Id or Name. Also what's the reason for the include are you using these properties in code or filling an object?

Comment: @JakeRote I am using "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final". And the reason for the include is i am building up a xml file to be serve to an ajax request. The file is a configuration file for freeswitch which has nested elements. That is the reason to include the sub entities.

Comment: Is it possible that the Navigation Properties used in Includes are keyed on foreign keys?